# spark remove updatestatebykey status

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I want to run the job and save to `Hbase` every **10 mins**. Now I use `updatestatebykey` to update state every **2 mins** and save `Hbase` at **10 mins**. 
Could I know how to calculate this 10 mins and how to reflesh `updatestatebykey` state every **2 mins**?  
I do this because reduce every 10 mins needs to much memory.

Comment: what had you tried so far?

Comment: i used updateStateBykey at this monent. it's work. but i do not know how to reflesh the status of updateStateBykey and calculate the 10 min..actually i do not contorll about the time.  if i unable the state, i do not know how to enable it again as well

Comment: requirement is save HBASE every 10 mins, run updateStatebykey every 2 min. reflesh state after save to HBASE

Comment: Are you in streaming or in batch mode ?